# Show/Hide label on condition in web user control in mvc4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to show/hide label on certain condition in my user control (.ascx). I tried following approaches but unable to achieve my desired output. What am I missing here?

**Approach - 1: Using jQuery**

.cshtml:

```
<fieldset id="delivery-threshold-fieldset">
    <legend>Delivery Threshold</legend>

    <div style="display: none" id="delivery-threshold-fieldset-message">
       <%= Html.Label("Please uncheck ENABLE THIRD PARTY DELIVERY PROVIDERS FOR THIS STORE option under DELIVERY to enable this section.") %>
    </div> 

</fieldset>
```

.js:

```
if (isThirdPartyDeliveryProviderAvailable.toString().toLowerCase() === 'true') {
    $("#delivery-threshold-fieldset-message").show();
} else {
    $("#delivery-threshold-fieldset-message").hide();
}
```

Output:

[image]

**Approach - 2: If condition.**

```
<fieldset id="delivery-threshold-fieldset">
    <legend>Delivery Threshold</legend>

    <% if (this.Model.IsThirdPartyDeliveryProviderAvailable)
       { %>
        <%= Html.Label("Please uncheck ENABLE THIRD PARTY DELIVERY PROVIDERS FOR THIS STORE option under DELIVERY to enable this section.") %>
    <% } %>

</fieldset>
```

Output:

[image]

In approach - 2, condition is getting satisfied while debugging but when I inspect the element on browser I don't see label at all. Not sure why?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why second approach does not work is because the way you are using `Html.Label`

On [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg453833(v=vs.98).aspx) it says

> Returns an HTML label element and the **property name** of the property
>   that is represented by the specified expression.

So I think your string contain **.** which may cause the helper to think it is expression.

Instead, try use the second overload such as:

```
Html.Label("", "Please uncheck ENABLE THIRD PARTY DELIVERY PROVIDERS FOR THIS STORE option under DELIVERY to enable this section.")
```

But in my opinion, since you are not associating this label with any input, why not just create simple html label instead of using helper:

```
<label>"Please uncheck ENABLE THIRD PARTY DELIVERY PROVIDERS FOR THIS STORE option under DELIVERY to enable this section."</label>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I got my desired result, I have posted my answer with the logic.

Answer (score 0):

I made a small change in my **Approach - 1 (.cshtml)** for desired result.

```
<fieldset id="delivery-threshold-fieldset">
    <legend>Delivery Threshold</legend>
    <div style="display: none" id="delivery-threshold-fieldset-message">
      <h2>
          <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsThirdPartyDeliveryProviderAvailable, "Please uncheck \"ENABLE THIRD PARTY DELIVERY PROVIDERS FOR THIS STORE\" option under \"DELIVERY\" to enable this section") %>
      </h2>
    </div> 
</fieldset>
```

Instead of **Html.Label** I used **Html.LabelFor**